# CnosDB after the environment is deployed, show database prompts: "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: docker, cnosdb

After the environment is deployed, show database prompts: "502 Bad Gateway"

```
[root@meta3 ~]# cnosdb-cli  -P 11112
CnosDB CLI v2.3.0
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 11112, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, precision: None }
public ❯ show databases;
502 Bad Gateway, details: <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>


Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: anyhow::__private::format_err
   2: client::ctx::SessionContext::sql::{{closure}}
   3: client::exec::exec_and_print::{{closure}}
   4: client::exec::exec_from_repl::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb_cli::main::{{closure}}
   6: cnosdb_cli::main
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   8: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   9: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  10: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  11: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  12: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  13: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  14: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  15: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  16: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  17: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  18: main
  19: __libc_start_main
  20: <unknown>
public ❯
```

version: cnosdb 2.3.2, revision 09985b3324732d94829fa1a74225e1e76cbc1d10

I encountered the above error when running CNOSDB on Docker. Have any of you encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you use http commands directly to manipulate docker? Looks like you can't connect to docker